# Run R codes by group

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have the following code to find days when both max & temperatures are > the corresponding 90th percentiles. The code works fine when I have a data frame for one station (`df`).

```
#data for one station
df
  Date     tmax  tmin  max90p min90p
 1962-7-2  31   21     29     19
 1962-7-3  32   23     29     19
  ...      ...  ...    ...    ...

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
d= df[, hotday := +(tmax>= max90p & tmin>=min90p)
][, EventLength := with(rle(hotday), rep(lengths,lengths))
][hotday == 0, EventLength := 0]
```

But I need to run this code for 133 stations so I have combined all stations in one data frame (`dfall`). I have tried to use `group_by()` in `dplyr` to run the code but did not work.

```
#All stations in one df
dfall
St_ID  Date     tmax  tmin  max90p min90p
4257   1962-7-2  31   21     29     19
...     ...      ...  ...    ...    ...
4263   1962-7-2  34   25     32     24
...     ...      ...  ...    ...    ...

d= dfall%>%
  group_by(St_ID)%>%
  dfall[, hotday := +(tmax>= max90p & tmin>=min90p)
  ][, EventLength := with(rle(hotday), rep(lengths,lengths))
  ][hotday == 0, EventLength := 0]


Error in `[.tbl_df`(., df00[, `:=`(hotday, +(tmax >= max90p & tmin >=  : 
  object 'hotday' not found
```

Any idea, thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

First, the `rleid()` and `fifelse()` functions can be used to streamline OP's code

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, hotday := +(tmax >= max90p & tmin >= min90p)][
  , EventLength := fifelse(hotday > 0, .N, 0), by = rleid(hotday)][]
```

> ```
>          Date tmax tmin max90p min90p hotday EventLength
> 1: 1962-07-02   31   21     29     19      1           2
> 2: 1962-07-03   32   23     29     19      1           2
> 3: 1962-07-04   28   17     29     19      0           0
> 4: 1962-07-05   27   18     29     19      0           0
> 5: 1962-07-06   31   21     29     19      1           3
> 6: 1962-07-07   32   23     29     19      1           3
> 7: 1962-07-08   32   23     29     19      1           3
> ```

(See the Data section below for reproducible data)

Now, `St_ID` can be included in the grouping.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfs)[, hotday := +(tmax >= max90p & tmin >= min90p)][
  , EventLength := fifelse(hotday > 0, .N, 0), by = .(St_ID, rleid(hotday))][]
```

> ```
>    St_ID       Date tmax tmin max90p min90p hotday EventLength
> 1:  4257 1962-07-02   31   21     29     19      1           2
> 2:  4257 1962-07-03   32   23     29     19      1           2
> 3:  4257 1962-07-04   28   17     29     19      0           0
> 4:  4257 1962-07-05   27   18     29     19      0           0
> 5:  4257 1962-07-06   31   21     29     19      1           1
> 6:  6342 1962-07-02   32   23     29     19      1           2
> 7:  6342 1962-07-03   32   23     29     19      1           2
> ```

#### Data

Reproducible data for a single station:

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread(
"Date      tmax tmin   max90p min90p
 1962-7-2  31   21     29     19
 1962-7-3  32   23     29     19
 1962-7-4  28   17     29     19
 1962-7-5  27   18     29     19
 1962-7-6  31   21     29     19
 1962-7-7  32   23     29     19
 1962-7-8  32   23     29     19
")
```

Reproducible data for multiple stations (including column `St_ID`):

```
dfs <- fread(
"St_ID Date      tmax tmin   max90p min90p
 4257  1962-7-2  31   21     29     19
 4257  1962-7-3  32   23     29     19
 4257  1962-7-4  28   17     29     19
 4257  1962-7-5  27   18     29     19
 4257  1962-7-6  31   21     29     19
 6342  1962-7-2  32   23     29     19
 6342  1962-7-3  32   23     29     19
")
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be mixing flavors: `tidy` pipe and `data.table` chaining. The last pipe is not working to feed into last step which does not receive a data.table as first parameter.

Consider base R's `by` to run calculation across each station subset and then bind together at the end:

```r
stations_dts <- base::by(df, df$St_ID, function(sub) {
  sub_dt <- setDT(sub)
  sub_dt[, hotday := +(tmax>= max90p & tmin>=min90p)
       ][, EventLength := with(rle(hotday), rep(lengths,lengths))
       ][hotday == 0, EventLength := 0]
})

final_dt <- data.table::rbindlist(station_dts)
```

Alternatively, you can possibly add station as grouping in your calculation by using the `by` argument in `[...]`. See docs on [`Extract.data.table`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.5.2/topics/Extract.data.table).

```r
dt <- setDT(df)
setkey(dt, St_ID)

dt[, hotday := +(tmax>= max90p & tmin>=min90p)
   , by=St_ID
  ][, EventLength := with(rle(hotday), rep(lengths,lengths))
    , by=St_ID
  ][hotday == 0
    , EventLength := 0
    , by=St_ID]
```

<sup>Note: above code needs testing on actual data.</sup>

Comment: The alternative approach using [tag:data.table] grouping can be streamlined to avoid repeated grouping by the same grouping variable `by=St_ID`:   `setDT(dfs)[, c("hotday", "EventLength") := {
  hotday <- +(tmax >= max90p & tmin >= min90p)
  EventLength <- fifelse(hotday > 0, with(rle(hotday), rep(lengths,lengths)), 0)
  list(hotday, EventLength)
}, keyby = St_ID][]`

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. It works well.

Comment: It's even simpler. Grouping by `St_ID` is only required for the `rle()` part. So, `setDT(dt)[, hotday := +(tmax>= max90p & tmin>=min90p)][
  , EventLength := with(rle(hotday), rep(lengths,lengths)), by=St_ID][
    hotday == 0, EventLength := 0]` will work as well.